# Duplicate entries in QtCreator's Project View with a cmake project

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

After opening my company's cmake project in QtCreator, every source file is listed 4 times in the Project View, like this:

```
MyProject
   CMakeLists.txt
   SubProj1
      CMakeLists.txt
      CMakeLists.txt
      CMakeLists.txt
      CMakeLists.txt 
      SourceFile1.cpp
      SourceFile1.cpp
      SourceFile1.cpp
      SourceFile1.cpp
   SubProj2
      CMakeLists.txt
      CMakeLists.txt
      CMakeLists.txt
      CMakeLists.txt
      SourceFile2.cpp
      SourceFile2.cpp
      SourceFile2.cpp
      SourceFile2.cpp
```

etc.

Why does it happen and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some CMakeLists.txt code for us?

Comment: Actually I have already found out that the duplication was caused by the fact that in project build settings CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES was assigned several values. After setting this variable to contain just one value per one QtCreator build configuration, the duplication dissapeared. But thanks anyway!